# Updating deprecated use reformulate()

Tags: r

Fairly new to coding and I'm geting a deprecation warning on.  I'm writing all the columns I want to perform analysis on to the variable 'cols'.  I am then looping through them to perform my analysis.  I'm gettign a deprecation warning for my use of the reformulate() function.

> Error in aov.model[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

> Warning messages:
> 1: In reformulate(termlabels = "Treatment", response = x) :
> Unparseable 'response' "10 DAP Plant Density"; use is deprecated.  Use as.name(.) or `..`!
> :1:4: unexpected symbol
> 1: 10 DAP
> ^
> 2: In reformulate(termlabels = "Treatment", response = x) :
> Unparseable 'response' "10 DAP Plant Density"; use is deprecated.  Use as.name(.) or `..`!
> :1:4: unexpected symbol
> 1: 10 DAP

Any advice for correcting the error and warnings?

```
######  Assign column names ######

cols <- names(data)[16:ncol(data)]
#cols <- names(data)[16:24]
cols

######  Analysis of variance model ######

for(i in 1:ncol(data[-c(1:3)])) {
  cols <- names(data)[16:ncol(data)]
  #cols <- names(data)[16:24]
  aov.model <- lapply(X = cols, FUN = function(x) 
  aov(reformulate(termlabels = "Treatment", response = x), data = data))
  # print df, MS and Pvalue
  final = anova(aov.model[[i]])[,c(1,3,5)]
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: also why for loop? your aov model does not depend on `i` meaning it will be the same.